# RHEL6 Crontab doesn't work properly?

Tags: linux, bash, cron, crontab, redhat-enterprise-linux

In RHEL6 root's account I have crontab job:

`30 6 18 4 1     /sbin/init 6`

It worked fine on the 18th of April and properly restarted my system, BUT it also restarted my OS at 6:30 on next Monday - 25th of April.
Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

You want this instead:

```
30 6 18 4 * /sbin/init 6
```

The `1` you have tells it to run every Monday as well. See [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron):

> While normally the job is executed when the time/date specification fields *all* match the current time and date, there is one exception: if both "day of month" and "day of week" are restricted (not "*"), then **either** the "day of month" field (3) or the "day of week" field (5) must match the current day.

Comment: Thanks as well WhiteFang34, I missed this "either" word :)

Answer (score 0):

From the `crontab(5)` man page:

> ```
>    Note: The day of a command’s execution can be specified by two fields —
>    day  of  month,  and  day  of week.  If both fields are restricted (ie,
>    aren’t *), the command will be run when either field matches  the  cur-
>    rent time.  For example,
>    "30  4  1,15 * 5" would cause a command to be run at 4:30 am on the 1st
>    and 15th of each month, plus every Friday.
> ```